# merge data from multiple Excel files with unique IDs

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel and I'm trying to merge data from multiple Excel files into one file with different sheets. I have a sheet called "merged_sheet" with IDs listed in column A, and I have other sheets with data that correspond to some of those IDs.

I've tried using the VLOOKUP function, but it only returns the first match and some IDs are repeated in the other sheets. I need to insert new rows as needed and return all matches for each ID.

Is there a way to do this efficiently and with minimal manual work? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have been using the formula "Textjoin(",",TRUE, IF(sheet2!A3:A128=A3,sheet2!b3:b128,"") to return all matches comma separated in one cell. However, I am now trying to figure out how to insert the necessary rows and split the comma separated values into those cells. I have tried using the formula "IF(len(AD3)>0, (LEN(AD3)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE (AD3,",",""))))" in another column to determine how many cells should be inserted, but I am unsure of how to proceed from there. Can anyone suggest a solution or offer any advice on how to achieve this?

[the merged sheet contains all possible IDs listed in column A with only one instance of each ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jT06g.png)

[other sheets contains IDs in column A  along with additional information. these sheets may not have the all IDs or may have multiple rows with the same ID as shown in sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO9tQ.png)

my goal is to gather the information for each ID from all sheets and input it into the corresponding row. but I'm facing challenge when dealing with repeated IDs.
this is how I want the result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Kx6.png)

Comment: Q1: Does merged_sheet have other information you want to preserve besides the ID list? Q2: Do the other sheets have ID values that are not in your list of IDs in merged_sheet? That is, are you trying to filter out some of the IDs so they don't show?

Comment: I'm sorry for not providing enough details I edited the question. 1. no, merged sheet only contains all possible IDs.  2.no, other sheets only have IDs listed in merged sheet. but the problem is some of them have multiple matches for some of the IDs. I'm trying to make a merged table of all of the information in all files/sheets but in a way that each row in this table has data for the same ID from all of the files.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's going to be tough, if not impossible, without using VBA. However, perhaps I will ponder it further. My answer below will not give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using Power query to merge all the files. At that, if you have all the files stored in the same folder you can copy new files to that folder and the data will be added to merged sheet automatically. And than just use Filter function to filter data on the separate sheets. If you need more precise instructions, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're trying to do is merge a bunch of identical sheets and put them in a sorted order without doing any filtering, the answer is pretty easy. I think if you're trying to filter based on a list of IDs, the problem gets harder.

This solution will just merge all your sheets.

**Givens**

- Each sheet has an ID in column A and all the IDs mean the same thing. If the
  ID is blank, the entire row is blank.
- Each sheet has the same number of columns. In this example I use two
  columns in addition to the ID column.
- There is nothing in *merged_sheet* that you want to preserve.

**Solution**

To capture all the rows and columns in the sheet, for each sheet you need a formula like this: `FILTER( SheetA!$A:$C, LEN( SheetA!$A:$A ) > 0 )` which brings back Columns A through C for all rows in SheetA where column A is not blank.

Then, you just need to stack and sort them all. So, in my example I use three sheets. This formula would be the only thing you would put in cell A1 of your merged_sheet:

```
=SORT( VSTACK( FILTER( SheetA!$A:$C, LEN( SheetA!$A:$A ) > 0 )
              ,FILTER( SheetB!$A:$C, LEN( SheetB!$A:$A ) > 0 )
              ,FILTER( SheetC!$A:$C, LEN( SheetC!$A:$A ) > 0 ) ) )
```

That should be all you need. I suggest using Excel's built-in column filtering if you want to filter those results down to a specific set of IDs.